# displayed time value is not same as entered value

Tags: javascript

The following code is giving wrong output time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
     {
         var r = Date.parse(document.getElementById("dates").value);
         var r1 = new Date(r);
         document.write(r1);
         return  false;
     }   
</script>

<form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit= "return(validate());">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Date: <input  type="datetime-local" id="dates" name="dates">
    <br/>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit"  VALUE="Submit" >
</form>
```

thanks in advance. if the input time is 9:30 it is giving output as 11:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be correct output.
`<input type="datetime-local">` stores the value as per your system date-time setting (i.e.: date-time in your timezone and not the UTC time).
Therefore while reading the value through `Date.parse` you are actually getting the milliseconds adjusted with your time zone. i.e your time zone offset will be added/subtracted from entered date-time to get the absolute millisecond value.
But when you are creating the date again with `var r1 = new Date(r)` you are actually initializing the date with given millisecond with time zone set to your system time zone.  Therefore it will introduce the offset equal to your time zone offset due to return value of `Date.parse`.
By looking at your input and output it appears your time-zone is GMT + 1:30 :)

Comment: thanks for that. i changed system time to (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time.now its working